# Is this a texas sage?

Tags: species-identification, botany

So for a project in one of my classes we must identify two monocots and two dicots growing at our school. We've managed to identify all but one:

[image: plant!]
So more information:

- My school is in southern nevada
- It's about one foot tall
- It's growing with joshua trees and oak trees and some rosemary.

Update: I think it's a texas sage, but I'm not completely certain, verification would be nice.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. Looks like that link is private, and I cannot access it.

Comment: @TwistedGenes Thanks for informing me, I've posted the image

Comment: That's a good guess, but I doubt it is Texas sage or *Leucophyllum frutescens* -- which is a common urban landscape shrub in the USA southwestern deserts.  *L. frutescens* is more upright and bushier, and in particular, much grayer than the plant in your picture.  Can you provide better/more pictures, from different angles, and especially pictures of any flowers that might be present?